# how to make collapse number with hypen

Tags: java

I want to make my number in collapse format with hypen symbol.

Suppose my input is like  "**1,2**,4,6,**7,8,9**,**11,12**,14,**16,17,18,19**"

and i want output as below
 "**1-2**,4,6,**7-9**,**11-12**,14,**16-19**

Comment: Sounds like you need a loop and probably a `StringBuilder`...

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a homework question to me, but I'll at least point you in the correct direction.

Personally I would probably use StringTokenizer and split the string into an integer array. Then loop through the array and checking if the contents of the current position are related to the next position or not, then find a way to save the values and print them later. You might require a second loop to print later, however I think you could be creative and find a solution that would be faster with only a single loop. ;)

If you want to get fancy, I might take a look into recursion and seeing if you can do this using a single function and a string.

Hope you find this helpful and it sends you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to store all the inputs in an array, check if the next number in the array is equal to one higher than the one before and keep doing so until it isn't, when it isn't, replace the numbers in between with a "-".

Look into the .replace() method that comes with the String-class